# Makefile not prompting compiler to use optimization flag

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a simple makefile that I am using in bash to compile a C++ program and its associated .h files, not every .h file has a .cpp file associated with it.  I wrote a makefile where each dependency was called out explicitly and the CFLAG macro was used for each specific dependency and it did compile with the -O3 flag and ran nearly 3 times faster.  However, when I use this simpler, but somewhat more sophisticated makefile, it does not compile with the -O3 flag even though it is clearly included with the CFLAG macro.  Can someone point out to me what I am missing, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
OBJS = main.o Output_Files.o Calendar.o Random_Number_Generator.o \
       Algorithm.o Statistics.o
DEPS = Output_Files.h Calendar.h Random_Number_Generator.h Algorithm.h \
       Statistics.h 
CC=c++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -O3

all: economics

%o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $<

economics: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS)

main.o: main.cpp Data_Parser.h PDF_and_CDF.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp
```

Comment: You missed a `-o` in the `%o` rule: it should be `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<` or just `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<`. In the rule for `economics`, you need `-o $@`. Does that fix your problem?

Comment: No that does not fix the problem.  It compiles based on what you added but it is still obviously not using the -O3 flag.  When I write the dependencies explicitly in the make file and compile it, the code executes in 0.45 to 0.47 seconds.  In this version it executes in about 1.57 to 1.6 seconds.  The execution time is how i know it is not properly implementing the compiler optimization flag.

Comment: Make sure that your directory is clean (no `.o` file), then run `make economics` and post the full transcript of running `make`.

Comment: Doesn't the rule for the target `economics` need to be `$(CC) $(OBJS) -o $@`? Else it will build the executable with default name `a.out` I think.

Comment: CC is the macro for the C compiler, not the C++ compiler.  Normally, that is CXX.  The rule to build `economics` creates `a.out` and not `economics`.

Comment: Run `make -p`. You'll understand that it is better to use `CXX` & `CXXFLAGS` for C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule:

```
%o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $<
```

should be written with an extra dot:

```
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<
```

Also, you don't want `$@` in the command line, or (if you must have it) you need to prefix it with `-o`.

The makefile is not using the faulty rule but instead uses the default rule for building C++ object files, and that most probably doesn't use `$(CFLAGS)` but uses `$(CXXFLAGS)` instead.

`CC` is the macro for the C compiler, not the C++ compiler. Normally, that is `CXX`. Also, the rule to build `economics` actually creates `a.out` and not `economics`.

I'd prefer it if you wrote:

```
SRCS = main.cpp Output_Files.cpp Calendar.cpp Random_Number_Generator.cpp \
       Algorithm.cpp Statistics.cpp
OBJS = ${SRCS:.cpp=.o}

…

economics: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

Putting it all together gives this `new.makefile`:

```
SRCS = main.cpp Output_Files.cpp Calendar.cpp Random_Number_Generator.cpp \
       Algorithm.cpp Statistics.cpp
OBJS = ${SRCS:.cpp=.o}
DEPS = Output_Files.h Calendar.h Random_Number_Generator.h Algorithm.h \
       Statistics.h
CC = c++
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -O3

all: economics

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

economics: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS)

main.o: main.cpp Data_Parser.h PDF_and_CDF.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp
```

#### Running `make -n` with the old makefile

```
$ make -n -f old.makefile
c++ -c -Wall -O3 main.cpp 
c++    -c -o Output_Files.o Output_Files.cpp
c++    -c -o Calendar.o Calendar.cpp
c++    -c -o Random_Number_Generator.o Random_Number_Generator.cpp
c++    -c -o Algorithm.o Algorithm.cpp
c++    -c -o Statistics.o Statistics.cpp
c++ -o economics main.o Output_Files.o Calendar.o Random_Number_Generator.o Algorithm.o Statistics.o
$
```

#### Running `make -n` with the new makefile

```
$ make -n -f new.makefile
c++ -c -Wall -O3 main.cpp 
c++ -c -Wall -O3 Output_Files.cpp
c++ -c -Wall -O3 Calendar.cpp
c++ -c -Wall -O3 Random_Number_Generator.cpp
c++ -c -Wall -O3 Algorithm.cpp
c++ -c -Wall -O3 Statistics.cpp
c++ -o economics main.o Output_Files.o Calendar.o Random_Number_Generator.o Algorithm.o Statistics.o
$
```

This is still an abnormal way of writing the `make` rules on a number of grounds, one being the `$(CC)` vs `$(CXX)` change.  Normally, the `-c` option is not included in `$(CFLAGS)` or `$(CXXFLAGS)`.  Normally, you include `$(CFLAGS)` or `$(CXXFLAGS)` in the link line too (because some of the flags might affect linking). Often, you need libraries and related flags in the linker line too.

This leads to a more orthodox naming convention:

```
SRCS = main.cpp Output_Files.cpp Calendar.cpp Random_Number_Generator.cpp \
       Algorithm.cpp Statistics.cpp
OBJS = ${SRCS:.cpp=.o}
DEPS = Output_Files.h Calendar.h Random_Number_Generator.h Algorithm.h \
       Statistics.h
CXX  = c++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -O3
LDFLAGS  =
LDLIBS   =

all: economics

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<

economics: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

main.o: main.cpp Data_Parser.h PDF_and_CDF.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp
```

Comment: You're correct about CC vs CXX, so why continue using CC incorrectly in new.makefile?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: For consistency with the question — only.  I just finished adding an addendum pointing out that the result is still aconventional as a makefile.  I've just added the orthodox form of the makefile for good measure.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Leffler for your assistance, your recommendations work beautifully.  I need to study the shell script for an hour or so to make sure I understand it, so I may ask another question r two, but thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've just noticed that the `main.o` doesn't depend on the other headers in `$(DEPS)`, which is a little implausible.  You probably need to add `$(DEPS)` to RHS of the `main.o: …` line.  _(Or, alternatively, the fact that none of the other source files depends on `Data_Parser.h` or `PDF_and_CDF.h` is implausible instead.  You might need to look up [`makedepend`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend) and add a rule to update dependencies — classically, that's done with `make depend`. Doing so will make the `DEPS` macro largely redundant.)